# Fullscreen dialog to parent container

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I created a demo here, opening a dialog in a single page inside a div as a parent container. but the fullscreen covered the entire page. It is possible to set the width and height of a dialog the same to its parent container?

**.html file**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  Angular Material 2 App
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="parent-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
    <button (click)="openDialog()" mat-button>
      open dialog
    </button>
</div>
```

**.ts file**

```
openDialog() {
    const dialog_ref = this.dialog.open(EntryComponent, {
      panelClass: ['full-screen']
    });

    dialog_ref.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {});
}
```

**.css file**

```
.full-screen .mat-dialog-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  .mat-dialog-content {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 85% !important;
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-specifying-dialog-parent)**

Comment: Using Bootstrap also you can do same thing.

Comment: @Laxmipriya sorry but im only using angular material2

Comment: What do you mean by 'It is possible to determined the limit of fullscreen dialog to its parent container only?' Do you mean set the size of the dialog based on the size of the parent container?

Comment: @G.Tranter i edited my post to make it clear and yes i would like to fullscreen a dialog to its parent container only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference to the parent container to pass its width and height to your openDialog() function for using with dialog.open(). For example:

```
<div #parent class="parent-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
    <button (click)="openDialog(parent.clientWidth, parent.clientHeight)" mat-button>
        open dialog
    </button>
</div>

openDialog(width, height) {
    const dialog_ref = this.dialog.open(EntryComponent, {
        width: width + 'px',
        height: height + 'px'
    });

    dialog_ref.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {});
}
```

Comment: the position of the dialog is centered, the overlay background covers the whole screen. seems like it is impossible to set the parent container of the matdialog where the overlay and dialog position is centered and limited only to parent container.

Comment: Read the [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) docs. You can turn off the overlay (hasBackdrop: false), control the size as my example shows, set the position, and more. You'll have to do some work to get the position right, but the other things are straightforward.